# how to make vue component to your own?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-cli

I have a simple vue-cli project with one component "vue-sweet-calendar" that I want to move away from node_modules into my own src/components folder because I need to modify it and it's no longer maintained.
How can I make it work?

now it's referenced in App.vue like this:

```
import { Calendar } from 'vue-sweet-calendar'
import 'vue-sweet-calendar/src/styles/index.sass'
```

if i change to `import { Calendar } from './components/vue-sweet-calendar'`
project fails to compile

Comment: Please add the error message displayed when the compile fails.

Comment: Are you sure both paths are valid?